# include assembly function in c++ MinGW

Tags: c++, assembly, mingw

I want to include an assembly function in c++. I used google and found `extern int test(int,int)` this works fine in C but not in c++. What i have to do in C++?
My code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern int test(int,int);

int main () {
  std::cout<<test(2,2); //Here I get "../main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `test'"
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using eclipse with MinGW.

Comment: `extern "C" int test(int,int);`

Comment: Try surrounding the `extern` declaration with `extern "C" {}`

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: this causes the same error.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl _'this causes the same error.'_ Even after a complete rebuild??

Comment: I rebuild the project and still the same error.

Comment: Found the problem, MinGW adds underscores to function names, so it loked for _test and not for test. Now extern "C" works fine.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl You could write an answer with fixed code and explanation, and then you can accept your own answer. Or, you can delete the question if you (or anybody else) don't want to bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include assembly functions in C++ with `extern "C"`. Working example:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int test(int,int);

int main () {
  std::cout<<test(2,2);
  return 0;
}
```

MinGW adds an underscore to the function, so you have to name it `_test` in assembly.